# Inputting text file into 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, file, multidimensional-array

Writing a method where I take a file, take the first two elements in the file as my rows and columns, then the rest as strings and fill a two dimensional array with them. This is my code so far, I keep getting an out of bounds exception. I am supposed to throw an exception in the method header.

```
public static String[][] input( String x) throws Exception{
    Scanner in=new Scanner(new File(x));
    String a =in.next();
    String b =in.next();
    int i = Integer.parseInt(a);
    int j = Integer.parseInt(b);
    String [][]table = new String[i][j];
    for(int count1=0;count1<table.length;count1++){
        for(int count2=0;count2<table[i].length;count2++){
            table[i][j] = in.next();
        }
    }
    return table;

    }
```

Content of the file:
8   5
black   red white   blue    orange
Cardinals   Cubs    Pirates Reds    Brewers
first   second  third   fourth  fifth
Zappa   Howe    Hackett Metheny Latimer
up  down    left    right   in
Anderson    Cheviot Covington Delhi Highland_Heights
Grateful_Dead Genesis Phish Van_der_Graaf_Generator Yes
ear eye mouth nose throat

Comment: Can you show the content of file?

Comment: right sorry, forgot to add it.

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone

Answer (score 0):

You are using `i` and `j` instead of `count1` and `count2`.

Replace `for(int count2=0;count2<table[i].length;count2++){` =>
`for(int count2=0;count2<table[count1].length;count2++){`

and 
`table[i][j] = in.next();` => `table[count1][count2] = in.next();`

Resultant code:

```
public static String[][] input( String x) throws Exception{
    Scanner in=new Scanner(new File(x));
    String a =in.next();
    String b =in.next();
    int i = Integer.parseInt(a);
    int j = Integer.parseInt(b);
    String [][]table = new String[i][j];
    for(int count1=0;count1<table.length;count1++){
        for(int count2=0;count2<table[count1].length;count2++){
            table[count1][count2] = in.next();
        }
    }
    return table;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `table[i][j] = in.next()` with  `table[count1][count2] = in.next()` and `count2<table[i].length` with `count2<table[count1].length`.

```
for(int count1=0;count1<table.length;count1++){
   for(int count2=0;count2<table[count1].length;count2++){
        table[count1][count2] = in.next();
   }
}
```